# IOS Safari support plugins?

Tags: ios, plugins, safari

I'm currently working on ipad IOS Safari. Thinking of adding some plugins to the application. but found some article saying that IOS Safari doesn't support plugins. Any expert know how true is the statement? Thanks

Comment: External plugins are not supported by a uiwebview, and are cause for rejection from the app store.

Comment: However, iOS Safari does seem to support bookmarklets, which can sometimes add plugin-like functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Safari, like all iOS apps, does not support plug-ins or any other form of customization.  Your only option is to create an app with a UIWebView.  Quite a few browser apps can be found in the App Store.

iOS 9 update: Safari still does not support plug-ins; however, it is now possible to build an app that [blocks specific content](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9.html) via a JSON file.  Content blocking rules only affect the Safari app and the new SFSafariViewController (UIWebView and WKWebView instances are unaffected).

Comment: This is no longer accurate as of iOS 9 (still in beta at the time of this comment).

Comment: Source for your claim, @JoshuaNozzi? (Not doubting, but wanting more information)

Comment: It's a major feature of iOS 9. Google can give you many sources, including news of Ad blocking controversies that resulted from it.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you need to jailbreak it to use them actually proves that Apple is not supporting the use of plugins.

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 9, browser plugins are supported (as content blockers).

Answer (score 3):

It DOES support plug-ins, you have to be Jailbroken to add any though. Install iFile from cydia then in iFile go to /System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins

The QuickTime Plugin is in there already, which proves that plugins are supported

And you can customize apps if your jailbroken