# JavaFX - can it really be deployed in a browser?

Tags: browser, javafx, ria

I have done some research on JavaFX over the last year, and even built some basic desktop apps with it.

It's described as being used to create RIAs (Rich Internet Application).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javafx

But can it *really* be deployed by a web browser? I have only deployed it via an executable JAR file.

How easy is it to deploy via web browser? Does it work? Does anyone have experience with this?

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm

Comment: Why bother using JavaFX in the browser? Just stick with the usual stack.

Comment: Tip: For building a web app user-interface using Java in a manner similar to JavaFX/Swing, consider [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

*Update for the March 2018 Java Client Roadmap*

I encourage readers interested in this question to review the following Oracle Whitepaper:

- [Java Client Roadmap Update](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf)

The above paper outlines the official Oracle position on related technologies (JavaFX/Swing/AWT/Applets/WebStart), the dates until which it intends to support those technologies and which of those technologies it intends to transition to open source development projects separate from the JDK and JRE.

*Update for Java 9, Oct 2017*

According to the [Java 9 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html):

> Java Applet and WebStart functionality, including the Applet API, The Java plug-in, the Java Applet Viewer, JNLP and Java Web Start including the javaws tool are all deprecated in JDK 9 and will be removed in a future release.

So, for Java 9+, deployment of JavaFX in a browser using a Java plug-in will only be possible using deprecated technology.  Oracle notes in another part of the [Java 9 release notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-9205ABFD-2024-40C8-B01E-A7328BBE4276):

> Deprecates the Java Plug-in and associated applet technologies in Oracle's JDK 9 builds.  While still available in JDK 9, these technologies will be considered for removal from the Oracle JDK and JRE in a future release.  Applets and JavaFX applications embedded in a web page require the Java Plug-in to run. Consider rewriting these types of applications as Java Web Start or self-contained applications.

Note: Java Web Start isn't really an alternative as that is also deprecated (anyway, it's different from an application embedded and rendered within a browser page).  Also note for those who wish to use Web Start, even though it has now been removed from Oracle JDK 11+, it is available as open source, info on this is at [OpenWebStart](https://openwebstart.com/).

As an alternative which offers similar functionality, consider something like [jpro](https://www.jpro.one), which deploys JavaFX applications in a browser without a Java plugin (jpro is currently only in closed beta, so it is not a viable solution as of October 2017, but maybe someday in the future...).

For now, I would recommend that the best way to deploy JavaFX applications is as [self-contained applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG585), running outside a browser.

---

*Previous answer for Java 7 and 8*

> JavaFx - can it really be deployed in a browser?

Yes, JavaFX applications can be deployed so that they run inside a web browser hosted html web page.

The technology which allows this to occur is the [Java Plugin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141438.html).  This plugin is currently a [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) based browser plugin solution.  The Java Plugin is shipped with the [Oracle Java 7 Runtime Standard Environment](http://www.java.com/getjava/%E2%80%8E).

Not all browsers are supported, only those listed on the [JavaFX Supported Configurations page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html).

> How easy is it to deploy via web browser?

The easiest way to deploy a JavaFX project in a web browser is:

1. [Create a new JavaFX project in NetBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/).
2. [Develop a simple HelloWorld App](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm).
3. Follow the instructions for [Deploying your first JavaFX Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/basic_deployment.htm).

This is not difficult (in my opinion).

Alternatively, follow instructions on the detailed reference for [Deploying JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) (or use 3rd party tools).  For many projects, using a tool other than the NetBeans IDE to perform packaging is a better approach.  However, it is generally easier to let the NetBeans IDE handle deployment packaging tasks for you.

---

What follows is not related to answering the original question, but provides some opinions and information requested in comments on this answer.

*Some Advice*

There are pitfalls to deploying Java in a browser. I encourage you to do your own Google research on the subject.

In my mind, based upon the current JavaFX 2.x deployment model, for most application types that require a browser as the primary runtime container, using JavaFX is not an appropriate solution.

Examine the deployment and runtime requirements for your application. Based on your requirements, and knowledge of the JavaFX browser based execution model, decide if a browser based deployment using JavaFX technology is the correct mechanism for your application.

*A couple of potential difficulties for browser embedded JavaFX applications*

Some important browsers (e.g. [Internet Explorer 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh968248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [iOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708342/ios-safari-support-plugins) and soon [Desktop Chrome](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/09/chrome-to-gradually-drop-support-for.html)) don't permit execution of plugins using the NPAPI currently used by the Java browser plugin => some of your target users may be unable to use your application.

With a browser embedded application, you don't have complete control over the runtime on which your application executes (browser + Java runtime + plugin interface) => an application which was working when first installed may stop functioning as expected after an update to these runtime components.

*Deployment Alternatives*

If a browser based deployment model is not appropriate for your application, there are other ways to [deploy JavaFX applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_overview.htm#CEGHEAHD) (e.g. WebStart, stand-alone jars and self-contained applications).

Comment: Thanks much for your comments. I think you would be doing everyone a big favor if you could list just your top 2-3 complaints about using JavaFX in a broswer.

Comment: OK, updated answer with a couple of potential difficulties (not complaints).

Comment: @jewelsea i want to run javafx on andorid. I read it here https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Building%20and%20deploying%20JavaFX%20Applications but not able to implement it..give me some suggestion ?

Comment: @anshul I have never used Android so I have no idea.  Asking a new question is better than commenting on a different one.  In your question you can describe what you tried and where you had an issue, then people can understand the difficulties better and learn from the solution.

Comment: I have recently tried JPro. It is out of beta and works well, albeit with some issues, which you can read about on their website.

Answer (score 51):

> JavaFX - can it really be deployed in a browser?

**No, not any more.**

The answer **used** to be yes, as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103168/157247), although even in 2013 when that was written the writing was on the wall. However, here in 2016 the answer is no, it cannot. Modern browsers essentially don't support NPAPI any longer (Firefox does for Java, but only until the end of the year), and NPAPI is required for the Java plugin.

Comment: interesting...that is some weird news to me

Answer (score 14):

As of 2016 you can use [jpro](http://www.jpro.io) without any browser plugin. And it even runs on mobiles.

Edit 1: The project is free for non-commercial or open source projects. A "hello world" can be found [here](https://github.com/jpro-one/HelloJPro)

Comment: where can I learn about this @KIC

Comment: it is stil beta you can subscribe to be notified when available or (i guess) ask for a beta access.

Comment: Can anybody show real working project on this technology?

Comment: Isn't jpro a commercial product that includes paid licensing?

Comment: @CuriousCoder it says: The non-commercial use of jpro is free of charge.

Comment: @user2602807, they have some demos on their website. I personally ended up never using it (but moved everything to react)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution by chance [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/). 
what  was missing in my web project.

I must add this to web.xml file :

```
 <mime-mapping>
    <extension>jnlp</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-java-jnlp-file</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: JNLP is deprecated in JDK 9 and hence this technique is not suggested. Check JDK 9 official documentation here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html