# Display panel-like graphic editor within JSP

Tags: java, jsp, graphics2d, piccolo

I am planning my first web project and currently evaluate, which technology to use. Since JSP seems to be a good start into webdev with Java, I was wondering if and how JSP is capable of displaying some complex graphic editing functionality. Think of a page with a panel (or canvas) in which you can create and edit graphical objects and also drag them around and stuff. Since I made some good experience with Piccolo2D framework for client applications, I'd like to use this again. 
Maybe you could provide a simple example of how to achieve this or tell me, which other Java webframework could do the job more efficiently (just to state the not-so-obvious: I really don't like to use JavaScript for this)
Thanks in advance...

Comment: *I was wondering if and how JSP is capable of displaying some complex graphic editing functionality.* JSP is irrelevant for that context. JSP, like PHP, ASP.Net or another web technology has the job to generate HTML dynamically. The stuff you have to do in client site is handled by HTML/JavaScript/CSS. JSP and any other web technology just helps you to generate proper HTML/JS/CSS content. Also, these web technologies can provide functionality on server side e.g. how to store/retrieve the data, but again, this is irrelevant for JSP.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. That is a very useful information. So, do you know how to achieve my described goal in particular without using javascript (and applets)?

Comment: If you cannot use JavaScript, then you should use another client server technology like Flash or, as you already said it, Applet. For your own set of requirements, seems impossible for an online application.

Comment: You may also consider using _JavaFX_. See for example [JavaFx - can it really be deployed in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19102000/1048330)