# Java Development Toolkit App Not Launching

Tags: javascript, java, java-web-start, eclipse-jdt, java-deployment-toolkit

I have designed a JavaFX application I would like to make accessible from my web server.  It is coded in Java, uses JavaFX, and I have attempted to make it accessible here: [bencitrin.com](http://bencitrin.com).

I tried embedding it into the homepage with the Java Development Toolkit.  However, I get an error: "JavaFX Application could not launch due to system configuration."

I am unsure how to go about this--I have tried running it both unsigned and self-signed.  Does it need to be "trusted"? The .jar works fine on my computer even though it is self-signed.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx - can it really be deployed in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102000/javafx-can-it-really-be-deployed-in-a-browser)

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) There is better support for **free-floating** JWS launched apps. 4) And a general debugging tip. Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: What technology are you asking about? "Java Development Toolkit", Eclipse JDT ("Java development tools"), or java-deployment-toolkit?