# Is it possible to run a JavaFX application in browser?

Tags: java, web, browser, javafx

I have a JavaFX (Maven) desktop application and I want to run it in a browser. Is it possible to do such a thing? If yes, which technology should I use?
I've been surfing the net quite a long time to find an answer but no convincing answer found.

Thank you :)

Comment: Possible? Yes... Advisable? Certainly not. The technology you are looking for is applets, and deploying your JavaFX application as an applet is covered in the [deployment guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/toc.html). Read "Execution Modes" (particularly embedded) and then start working through chapter 5. However, even if you get this working, getting a user to convince the web browser your applet is not a security risk is a whole other issue...

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102000/javafx-can-it-really-be-deployed-in-a-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102000/javafx-can-it-really-be-deployed-in-a-browser)

Comment: Note that the linked question is quite old, and that since that was posted, Oracle has announced plans to [deprecate the Java plugin](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: Unfortunately, the article is moved and the link of @James_D shows "Not found". Apparently the people in Oracle have never heard about redirecting of old content addresses to their new location (unlike the people of Microsoft - you can still open MSDN links from the year 2000). The new address of the article is here (for now) https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web Update of the blog post can be found here: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/updates-to-moving-to-a-plugin-free-web

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible or it will be possible. Here you can find more information:
http://jpro.io

and examples JavaFx application which run in browser. This technology is still under development but I hope that we recive more information in short time.

Comment: interesting project

Comment: That website no longer exists