# Is it possible to create java applets using JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, applet

I want to create an applet using Javafx Scene Builder. I know the traditional way of creating an applet but then I recently started working with JavaFx and I am in love with the way you can create awesome User Interface designs using Scene Builder and then write neat customized code. So, far I can create desktop programs using JavaFx but now I want to write small utility programs and embed it on a browser. I honestly dislike the idea of writing codes to create the U.I. of an applet, so I was thinking if there was a way to create an applet using Javafx.

P.S - I am new to Stackoverflow. So, please forgive any mistakes I make.

Comment: Look at non-applet browser deployment http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102000/javafx-can-it-really-be-deployed-in-a-browse

Answer (score 3):

Applets are a dead technology, so you should forget them altogether. Support for applets has been removed at least in the newest Chrome browser, and most likely others too.

<strike>It's not possible to create applets via JavaFX either.</strike>

Comment: It's still technically possible to create JavaFX applets, and Oracle still provides [tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/) to enable you to do so. However, you are [completely correct](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289) that this is a dead technology and you should look for alternative approaches.

Comment: @James_D My mistake. I was under the impression that JavaFX was never extended to applets, as they've been in a deprecated state for quite some time.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done thanks to a [`JFXPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) which allows to embed a `JavaFX` component into a `Swing` component and from a `Swing` component you can easily create an `Applet`.

**Here is an example that draws a `Java FX` `Rectangle` into an `Applet`:**

```
public class Main extends Applet {

    private void initAndShowGUI() {
        // This method is invoked on Swing thread
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        fxPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        add(fxPanel);
        setVisible(true);
        Platform.runLater(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initFX(fxPanel);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on JavaFX thread
        final Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createScene() {
        final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(100.0, 100.0);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        return new Scene(new VBox(rectangle));
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initAndShowGUI();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

---

However **Applets are outdated** and will be removed soon so if you can avoid using them, just don't use them. Alternatively you can use the `Deployment Toolkit library` to embed your `JavaFX application` in a web page or launch it from a browser, more details about this approach [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deployment_toolkit.html).

Comment: But you can create applets with JavaFX without embedding them in Swing. You should avoid mixing the two toolkits unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: @James_D if so please provide an answer then, I can propose only what I know if there is a better approach I would be happy to know it

Comment: The correct answer was provided by @Kayaman: Applets will be deprecated in Java 9 and you should avoid using them entirely (either with Swing or with JavaFX). I already provided a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/) below that question to the tools to create a JavaFX Applet for those who insist on ignoring the [official position](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289).

Comment: @James_D I already checked your link I can't see anything specific that explain how to do a JavaFX Applet, so do you have a more specific link to provide? Unless you meant this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deployment_toolkit.html? IMHO indicating that it is outdated should be more a comment or at worse a NB in an answer, rather than a real answer. Indeed maybe the OP doesn't have the choice so knowing that it is outdated doesn't help much

Comment: Every chapter in that guide covers all four [execution modes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deploy_overview.html#BABCGDJF) (1. standalone program, 2. Java Web Start, 3. Embedded in a browser, i.e. applet, and 4. self-contained application). I **completely** disagree about providing an answer that encourages the use of something that is explicitly deprecated: that is akin to misinformation imho.

Comment: @James_D I added a note indicating to not use it if possible, feel free to down vote if my answer is not correct for you, at least it will be a down vote with a comment which is still appreciable