# Hybrid Drupal 8 with unhosted web apps or JavaFX Web Start apps?

Tags: drupal

I'm looking into using Drupal as the "back end (ish)" for a web site I want to build. In my research I have discovered the concept of "hybrid" Drupal, where you use Drupal to organize the site and for the navigation controls around a "frame" where you can then put regular web-based content. My question is: What can go in that frame? Can you put anything that would go on a normal, plain-vanilla web page? What about "[unhosted web apps](http://unhosted.org/)"? What about a [JavaFX webstart](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm) app?

Comment: Hard to know what you are trying to do, but today's browsers are pretty hostile to Java deployment.  See [JavaFX - can it really be deployed in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102000/javafx-can-it-really-be-deployed-in-a-browser).  You could launch a JavaFX based webstart app through a browser, perhaps that is what you are referring to rather than an app rendered embedded in a web page.  But even that isn't going to work on a variety of platforms (e.g. iOS).  Currently as is, this question is probably closable as primarily opinion based, too broad or a library recommendation.

Comment: I don't agree with your reasons for closing. I just want to know if those things can be done within the "frame" provided by hybrid Drupal. In other words: Is there something about the hybrid Drupal environment which would preclude using those other technologies. I am not asking whether you approve of my use of those technologies. It seems your opinion about the deployability of JavaFX is clouding your opinion about the basis of my question.

Comment: Where did you learn about this "hybrid" drupal? I only know of "headless" Drupal, which is just a fancy way of saying that you use drupal as a webservice (via rest endpoints or alike).

Comment: Here is one link: http://albatrossdigital.com/node/37   I'm on my phone so that will have to do for now. I was searching to see if I could run web apps in a Drupal page. Other sites explain that hybrid Drupal puts a "frame" within a Drupal view that allows you to put any regular JavaScript you want in that frame. However, said site did not mention if said frame was a standard HTML frame, or something different. Nor did said site say what was allowed within said frame.  I have searched till I am blue in the face and I can't find much more information than this.