# An interactive real-time web application with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, web-applications, real-time

I'd like to design a web application with JavaFX.

There are several bits and pieces on the Net, but there's no complete clear response. Even here on **StackOverflow** are only bits and pieces to answers of the same question, so that don't really help.

What I really want is:

1. Develop a web application that allows one or more users to register and then have an account to access the web app (accordingly their data are stored in a database);
2. Then, the rest is basically some interactions between the users and the app. In other words, inputs are given by the users in the form of text and based on a programmed model (algorithm) they got answers/feedbacks (outputs) from the web app (dynamically and in real-time).
3. All interactions (history) between each user and the web app are stored in a database for future use.

So my question is : Is it possible to do so using JavaFX? If yes, what is the best approach and solutions to consider? If no, what are the best alternatives to achieve such requirements using Java (since the algorithm is coded in Java)?

Comment: Java FX is for desktop applications see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102000/javafx-can-it-really-be-deployed-in-a-browser

Comment: I have another question, is it possible to develop a desktop application with JavaFX that can store and collect data from a database installed in a server(let's say in the cloud or just an online server)? In other words, the desktop's app users can reach their data everywhere and anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a JavaFX application can connect over a network to various resources to aggregate data. There are many different approaches and API's that you can use to connect with different systems and services.

Comment: Can you suggest a few, please?