# How do I deploy a JavaFX application in an HTML page?

Tags: java, html

I have a JavaFx application. I tried several times to deploy it in an HTML page, but I got nothing. I use jre 9. I also tried to do it with Java web start, but when I open the HTML page, I get the following error: `Java security settings have blocked your local application to run`.

I changed my Java security settings in the Java control panel, but it's still not working. Please help me, how can I do this?

Comment: Please add more information to allow people to help you, how you embedded it to html with java web start, how you're serving html and so on. Also keep in mind that java web start (also java applets) are deprecated since Java 9.

Comment: Likely duplicate of [JavaFX - can it really be deployed in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102000/javafx-can-it-really-be-deployed-in-a-browser)

Comment: so, how to deploy javafx application in a html page without java web start